# Track When Program Installed

Tags: windows-xp, installation, uninstall, event-log

Is it possible to set an audit policy to track when a program has been installed or uninstalled? Not using MSI installer at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** On Windows, an installer is just an ordinary Windows program, it doesn't generate audit log entries automagically.

**However,** you *can* enable auditing for folder (or registry key) creation in the `%ProgramFiles%` folder and the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` registry branch (`regedit`, right-click, *Permissions*). In both cases, the auditing settings are hidden under *Advanced -> Auditing*.